# The Weyl Scalar: does anyone here knows a code to calculate it?

Tags: physics, tensors, code-request

From pure differential geometry we have an important tensor called *Weyl Tensor*. Its components are given by:

> $$C_{ijkl} = R_{ijkl} - \frac{2}{n-2}(g_{ik}R_{jl} + g_{jl}R_{ik} - g_{il}R_{jk} - g_{jk}R_{il} ) - \frac{2}{(n-1)(n-2)}R(g_{il}g_{jk} - g_{ik}g_{jl}).\tag{1}$$

I would like to calculate via a mathematica code the scalar given by:

> $$W = C_{ijkl}C^{ijkl} \tag{2}$$

**Does anyone knows a code for this one calculation $(2)$ (given, of course, a metric tensor matrix)?**

Comment: Note: if you want to do tensor calculus in Mathematica in general, you might be interested in the package [`xAct`](http://www.xact.es/).

Comment: @thorimur I used another software to combine code lines. It is here in my personal  website: https://sites.google.com/view/curvedrealityblog/texts-in-physics/mathematica-and-similar-softwares?authuser=0